# AGrig React get valued from getDisplayedRowCount() into container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I can successfuly console.log the value by doing

```
console.log(this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount());
```

inside onGridReady on my component.

id like to get this valued and pass it from this component over to another component so I can display the number of rows each time.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use local state.
Then set local state to be the value of this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount()
React will then take care of the re-rendering.
But you will be able to use state to render the data.

Comment: Hi, Thank you.  Could you elaborate on that please?